# Storybooks.js modifiying inner state, when an inner http call exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

so I am using storybooks.js, and I want to change the state:

in the documentation, I saw: `https://storybook.js.org/basics/faq/` and the

```
<MyComponent initialState={{ someVar: 'otherVal' }});
```

but the problem is, that in my component I have a `componentDidMount`, which makes a call to `localhost:8000`, and when hosted on a static website will always fail.

I thought about passing an extra prop i.e `storybook`, and in the `componentDidMount` do something like this, but I don't want to change it like this.

```
if (props.storybook) {
  this.setState({ rows: ... })
} else {
  axios
    .get('http://wwww.localhost:8080/api/track/toptracks?limit=250')
    .then(response => {
```

or

```
if (props.storybook) {
  axios
    .get('http://wwww.localhost:8080/api/track/toptracks?limit=250')
    .then(response => {
```

Does anyone have some kind of suggestions how to deal with this situation?

Thank You in forward!

Comment: the `if` statement is working, curious if there is a more pretty solution

Comment: Can't you mock the axios requests with for example https://github.com/axios/moxios? When setting up Storybook, you mock the result for http://wwww.localhost:8080/api/track/toptracks?limit=250. Then you don't need to change the code in your component